# Random pro-p groups via iterated uniformly random central extensions

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability, group-cohomology, profinite-groups, p-groups

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503748/what-is-the-cohomology-tree-probability-distribution) on math.se, I want to understand the following construction of a random pro-$p$ group:

We want to construct an inverse system 
$$\cdots \xrightarrow{\alpha_i} G_i \xrightarrow{\alpha_{i-1}} \cdots \xrightarrow{\alpha_2} G_2 \xrightarrow{\alpha_1} G_1$$
where $G_i$ is a group of order $p^n$ and $\alpha_i$ fits in a central extension
$$ 1 \rightarrow \mathbb F_p \rightarrow G_{i+1} \xrightarrow{\alpha_i} G_i \rightarrow 1$$

We start with $G_1 = \mathbb F_p$ and if we constructed the inverse system up to $G_i$, we take an uniformly random element of $\eta \in H^2(G_i,\mathbb F_p)$ and choose a $G_{i+1} \xrightarrow{\alpha_i} G_i$ which fits in a central extension corresponding to $\eta$.

Then we can take the limit $\hat G$ of this inverse system. This should define a probability measure on the isomorphism classes of pro-$p$ groups of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

This description is maybe a bit sloppy concerning set theoretical issues, so to make it work in any case, we could refine us to a skeleton $\mathcal C$ of the category of p-groups (with $\mathbb F_p \in \mathcal C$) and choose maps
$$ H^2(G,\mathbb F_p) \rightarrow \{1 \rightarrow \mathbb F_p \rightarrow E \xrightarrow{\alpha} G \rightarrow 1 \text{ central extension in } \mathcal C\}$$
in beforehand.

> **Questions**
>
> 1. I would expect $\hat G$ to be "as bad as possible". E.g. it should be almost surely non-abelian. Is it almost surely topologically finitely generated?
>      Is it also almost surely not solvable?
> 2. Given a finite p-group $H$, is it almost surely a quotient of $\hat G$? This would answer the first question immediately.
> 3. Is there an interesting property of $\hat G$ which has probability $0 \lt q \lt 1$?
> 4. As a negative answer to question 3, is there a pro-$p$ group $\hat H$, so that $\hat G \cong \hat H$ almost surely? If so, can you give a
>      nice description of $\hat H$? For example, is it the free pro-$p$
>      group on countable many generators?

Edit: I am not so sure anymore whether it's almost surely not topologically finitely generated. $\hat G$ is finitely generated if $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(G_n) \lt \infty$ where $d(G_n)$ is the minimal number of generators. I think that $d(G_{n+1}) = d(G_n) + 1$ holds for $\eta = 0 \in H^2(G_i, \mathbb F_p)$ and $d(G_{n+1}) = d(G_n)$ for all nonzero $\eta \in H^2(G_i, \mathbb F_p)$. By Golod-Shafarevich
$$\dim H^2(G_n, \mathbb F_p)  \gt \frac{1}{4}\cdot d(G_n)^2$$
so $d(G_n)$ will grow very slowly. But this is of course not enough to show that $\hat G$ is almost surely finitely generated.